# Python unittest for modules

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to run a Python [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) by invoking the

```
python -m unittest discover
```

command. Two packages are in in a module as follows

```
test
 |_ mytest.py
my_module
  |__foo.py
  |__bar.py
```

where in **bar.py**

```
#bar.py
from foo import baz
# Do things using baz
```

The problem is that when the unittest discover command runs, **foo** cannot be found in **bar.py** anymore. This because **my_module** is seen as a proper module inside the python test, so I would need to do

```
from my_module.foo import baz
```

but that wouldn't work when using the module stand-alone. So what to do? I see 2 options, but they are not that neat so I would like more input:

1. Let **init**.py in my_module add my_module to PYTHONPATH
2. Let mytest.py add my_module to PYTHONPATH

However, I found [this page](https://ncoghlan-devs-python-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap) stating that

> Never add a package directory, or any directory inside a package,
>   directly to the Python path.

The arguments put forth seems to make sense, and as our repository grows constantly we should try to get this right.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make any changes to `my_module` to turn it into a package that can be imported by your unit tests, one solution is to move your unit tests into `my_module`. For example, you could have:

```py
# my_module/bar.py

from foo import baz
```

```py
# my_module/test_bar.py

import bar

# Tests...
```

Then run `python -m unittest discover` from inside `my_module` or `python -m unittest discover --start-directory my_module` from the project root.

By the way, I think there might be some confusion with terminology here. In Python, a module is typically a single `.py` file, and a package is typically a folder that contains a group of `.py` files, one of which is `__init__.py`. For that reason,  `foo` and `bar` are probably really modules, and `my_module` is probably a package (or would be if it had an `__init__.py` file).

Answer (score 1):

If you ALSO want to have those modules STANDALONE, then they should NOT be INSIDE another module.
Because that way, you are ALREADY violating "Never add a page directory inside a module..."
And then you could add that path to the pythonpath as well.